# Получить все атрибуты каждого элемента формы

Tags: php, javascript, html

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите как Получить все атрибуты каждого элемента формы средствами php.

```
<form action="1.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal"> 
<table id=AnGeL class=table_style_2 style='width: auto;'>
<tr><td>Логин</td><td><input type="text" name="usr_ogrnip" readonly value="1111"</td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Пароль</td><td><input type="text" name="usr_passwd"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Роль</td><td><select name="usr_level">
<option selected value="<?php echo $site_users->usr_level;?>"><?php echo show_usr_level($site_users->usr_level);?></option>
<option value="1"><?php echo show_usr_level(1);?></option>
<option value="2"><?php echo show_usr_level(2);?></option>
<option value="0"><?php echo show_usr_level(0);?></option>
</select></td></tr>
</table>
<input type='hidden' name='url_user_id' value=444><input type='hidden' name='update' value='1'><input type="submit" id=btn value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
```

написал на php как вывести все элементы формы и их значения

```
<SCRIPT>
function fnGetAtt(eId){ var attrs = eId.attributes;for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) { alert( attrs[i].name + " = " + attrs[i].value ); }}
</SCRIPT>
<?
$a1=array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){if ( is_array($value) ){foreach ($value as $i=>$val) {$a1[$i]=$val;}}else{$a1[$key]=$value;}}
foreach($a1 as $key => $value) {
 if ( !empty($value) ) {  echo '<SCRIPT>
  var tb = document.body.children[\''.$key.'\']
  fnGetAtt(tb);</SCRIPT>';
  echo "\$_POST[".$key."] = ".$value."<br>";}}
?>
```

Элементы формы ВСЕ выводит, а нужно чтоб выводил все тип у которых не (type='hidden') имя не usr_level и т.п. в общем нужно получить свойство и атрибуты каждого элемента в форме. Как это реализовать?

Спасибо!

Comment: `usr_level` Вы сами должны проверять, в цикле сравнивая ключи с ним. Тип поля, с которого пришло значение, средствами PHP вроде проверить невозможно

Answer (score 0):

PHP никакого отношения не имеет к вашей форме на HTML. PHP находится на сервере, HTML же в браузерах юзверей. В случае, если вам по каким-то причинам надо логически обрабатывать аттрибуты формы, то вы можете пойти 2 путями:

#### Определите структуру формы на сервере

При данном методе реализации предполагается неизменность структуры формы действиями пользователя. Предположим что у нас есть форма

```
<?php

$form = [
  'usr_ogrnip' => [
    'element' => 'input',
    'type' => 'text',
    'readonly' => true
  ],
  'usr_passwd' => [
    'element' => 'input',
    'type' => 'text' // Почему не password?!
  ],
  'usr_level' => [
    'element' => 'select',
    'values' => [
      [
          'selected' => true,
          'value' => '1'
      ],
      ['value'=>2],
      ['value'=>3]
    ]
  ],
  'url_user_id' => [
    'element' => 'input',
    'type' => 'hidden'
  ],
  'url_update' => [
    'element' => 'input',
    'type' => 'hidden'
  ]
];
```

Теперь, когда у нас есть структура формы, мы можем обратится к параметрам каждого поля, зная его name и value (которые передаются нам в $_POST)

```
$post_values = [];
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {

  if(isset($form[$key])) continue;
  // Проверим не hidden ли поле

  if($form[$key]['hidden'] ?? false) continue;
  // если PHP меньше 7, то 
  // if(isset($form[$key]['hidden']) && $form[$key]['hidden']) continue;

  // И проверим ещё и тип
  if('hidden' == ($form[$key]['type'] ?? '')) continue;

  // Проверим имя чтоб было не usr_level
  if($key == 'usr_level') continue;

  // Ну и в качестве примера сделаем чтоб в массив $post_values попали
  // Только <input> и без readonly аттрибута
  if('input' != ($form[$key]['element'] ?? '')) continue;
  if($form[$key]['readonly'] ?? false) continue;

  // Если поле прошло все фильтры, то занесём в $post_values
  // Это только пример. Не реализация задачи. Помните об этом.
  $post_values[$key] = $value;

}
```

#### Передайте структуру формы через Ajax

В таком случае вам надо через javascript распарсить HTML древо `<form>`,
найти там все поля, получить их имена, аттрибуты, значения если это `<select>` и т.д.

Однако в этических, моральных и целях безопасности мы этим заниматься не будем.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var val= function(elem,vl) {//получает||назначает value/innerHTML
  var req,
    a = elem,
    undef = vl!==undefined;//проверка на существование vl (ели true, то функция работает как setter и наоборот)
  if (a.nodeType == 1) {
    if (!a.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty("value")) {//проверяем, может ли быть value у элемента
      if (undef)//setter
        a.innerHTML = vl;
      else//getter
        req = a.innerHTML;
    } else {
      if (undef)//setter
        a.value = vl;
      else//getter
        req = a.value;
    }
  }
  return undef ? a : req;//в режиме setter возвращает сам элемент
},
attr = function(elem) {//получаем все атрибуты
  var req = {},
    allAttrs=elem.attributes;
  for (var key in allAttrs) {
    if (allAttrs[key].nodeName)
      req[allAttrs[key].nodeName] = allAttrs[key].nodeValue;
  }

  return req;
},
elems={};
form.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(el){//перебор всех элементов в форме
  var elname=el.tagName.toLowerCase(),
  attrs=attr(el);
  attrs.VALUE=val(el);
  elems[elname]===undefined&&(elems[elname]=[]);//создаём новое свойство, если такого тега ещё нет
  elems[elname].push(attrs);
});
console.log(elems);
```

```html
<div id="form">
<div id="div1" class="gg vp dd" style="lol"></div>
<div id="div1" class="gg1 vp dd" style="lol"></div>
<div id="div1" class="gg2 vp dd" style="lol"></div>
<textarea id="div1" class="gg vp3 dd" style="lol">sdassdasd</textarea>
<textarea id="div1" class="gg vp3 dd" style="lol" readonly></textarea>
<input name="ThisIsINPUT">asdasdasd</input>
<div id="div1" class="gg vp dd5" style="lol2"></div>
</div>
```

После чего можете спокойно отправлять этот объект через ajax и обрабатывать как вам нужно. Структура:

```
elems={
    tagName:[//массив всех элементов с одинаковыми тегами
        {//объект с атрибутами
            attr:"attr",
            attr:"attr",
            ...
            VALUE:"val"//значение(innerHTML или value) тега
        }
    ]
};
```